# checking for name of Pandas dataframe as a condition

Tags: pandas

When I want to check which Pandas dataframe is being called, how do I use the dataframe name in an if condition?

I keep getting "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous...." and can't figure out a way around it.

```
df_even = pd.DataFrame( data=[2,4,6,12,64,866,222])
df_prime = pd.DataFrame( data=[5,7,11,13,17,19]) 
df_list = [df_even, df_prime]

for frame in df_list:
    if frame == df_even:
        name = 'even'
    elif frame == df_prime:
        name = 'prime'
    # do something with the dataframe next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're testing for identity, you should use the `is` opertator.  Note the distinction between equality, i.e. the logical *values* of the two objects are the same, and identity, i.e. they are the *same object*, i.e., the two names refer to the same address in memory.

```
if frame is df_even:
    ...
```

Your original code isn't working because pandas overrides the `==` operator to perform a value-by-value comparison (rather than dataframe-level comparison). This special override is not returning a boolean as `==` ordinarily does.

---

[More about `==` vs `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python).

Comment: Perfect!.  Thanks for the detail as well.